# Unexpected output on parallel tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task, multitasking

I have to parallelelize an existing code. Basically, the code takes a file, do a work on it and save the result in a new file. And I need to do this work on a batch of files.

So, I do this example code to view what code structure I need, but it works weirdly:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Processor processor = null;
        ProcessAsync(processor, 3);
    }

    static void ProcessAsync(Processor processor, int n)
    {
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            processor = new Processor(i);
            tasks.Add(new Task(() => processor.Process()));
            tasks[i].Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            tasks[i].Wait();
        }
    }
}

class Processor
{
    private readonly int id;

    public Processor(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString("000") + ": " + "Processing...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString("000") + ": " + "Processed!");
    }
}
```

I expect this output:

```
Task 000: Processing...
Task 001: Processing...
Task 002: Processing...
Task 000: Processed!
Task 001: Processed!
Task 002: Processed!
```

But I have this result:

```
Task 002: Processing...
Task 002: Processing...
Task 002: Processing...
Task 002: Processed!
Task 002: Processed!
Task 002: Processed!
```

Why are all `processor`'s `id`s `002`?

Comment: That is an old classic, called 'capturing the loop var'

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding other issues, this is a capture and closer problem

You can search for as there are rheams of it written about it on the web, and its just the way the CLR and lambda work

The fix is just create a fresh new local variable

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    var proc = new Processor(i);
    tasks.Add(new Task(() => proc.Process()));
    tasks[i].Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking quickly it looks like it is to do with variable scope and folding scope into the lambda.

Try changing your loop so it is like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        tasks.Add(new Task(() => new Processor(i).Process()));
        tasks[i].Start();
    }
```

Also, ask if Processor really needs to be a class, could it not be a simple method? There is something odd about the logic where you pass in a Processor, but then create a new one for each loop iteration. Do you really want that?